# How do I Make Realistic Car Exhaust Come from an pipe?

Tags: smoke-simulation

I am making a 3D model of a car, and I wanted to ask how to make realistic smoke come from the exhaust pipes. I would like it if it could be seen both in a short movie, and also a still image render.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried the built-in Blender smoke simulator? There are lots of settings and tutorials on how to use it.

Comment: No I have never built one before, and i have looked at some of the tutorials but they are not super helpful.

Comment: I think it is one of those things you will just have to play at until you get a result you are happy with. Start really simple and just get a basic Smoke sim running like cigarette smoke then change the angle and density.